# Azure Track CloudBlockBlob Upload Progress

Tags: azure, blob

I would like the capability to track the progress of a CloudBlockBlob upload.
Current ways of doing this is to hook into the file stream reads on the client side which is not the same as the writing of that data on the server side in Azure.
Part of the complication is that I am not able to find a way to read the uncommitted Blob on Azure as the data is being written to it.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/03/06/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification-2-0.aspx.  Essentially this code is doing what you suggest - hooking into the stream reads - but it is the best option I have found.

The only other good way would be to download the storage client library source code and modify it to add events to the HTTP uploads.  The downside to this is that you will have to re-write that code every time you want to get an updated version of the SCL.